# Amazon Kubernetes AWS-EKS is not getting created properly or not synched with kubectl

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Following this document step by step:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html?shortFooter=true

I created EKS cluster using aws cli instead-of UI. So I got the following output

```
proxy-kube$ kubectl get svc 
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.100.0.1   <none>        443/TCP   18h
```

But when I am following this getting started and associating Worker nodes with the cluster, I get

```
proxy-kube$ kubectl get nodes 
No resources found.
```

I can see 3 EC2 instances created and running in AWS console (UI).
But I am unable to deploy and run even Guestbook application. 
When I deploy application, I get following:

```
~$ kubectl get services -o wide
NAME           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)          AGE       SELECTOR
guestbook      LoadBalancer   10.100.46.244    a08e89122c10311e88fdd0e3fbea8df8-1146802048.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   3000:32758/TCP   17s       app=guestbook
kubernetes     ClusterIP      10.100.0.1       <none>                                                                    443/TCP          21h       <none>
redis-master   ClusterIP      10.100.208.141   <none>                                                                    6379/TCP         1m        app=redis,role=master
redis-slave    ClusterIP      10.100.226.147   <none>
```

But if I try to access EXTERNAL-IP, It shows

> server is not reachable

in browser.

Also tried to get Dashboard for kubernetes but it failed to show anything on 127.0.0.1:8001

Does anyone know what might be going wrong? 
Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks you your kubelet (your node) is not registering with the master. If you don't have any nodes basically you can't run anything.

You can ssh into one of the nodes and check the logs in the kubelet with something like this:

```
journalctl -xeu kubelet
```

Also, it would help to post the output of `kubectl describe deployment <deployment-name>` and `kubectl get pods`

Comment: Thanks Rico for the answer, The deployments I was also intact, but the pod was not up. But in the mean time I deleted everything and re created, as this time i had  aws-iam-authenticator already installed, and I could get the nodes and could successfully run guestbook application.