# No nodes available in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to setup an AWS EKS cluster and followed the instructions in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html. But  while trying to setup the dashboard I realized I do not have any nodes and don't know why.

Yes, I made sure that the CloudFormation stack for my nodes has the exact name of my EKS cluster and I applied the `aws-auth-cm.yaml` with the stacks `NodeInstanceRole`.

A similar question came up here [Amazon Kubernetes AWS-EKS is not getting created properly or not synched with kubectl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542933/amazon-kubernetes-aws-eks-is-not-getting-created-properly-or-not-synched-with-ku) but there is no usable information there.

Here is some info:

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   <IP>         <none>        443/TCP   11d

$ kubectl get all --namespace=default
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   <IP>         <none>        443/TCP   11d

$ kubectl get nodes --namespace=kube-system
No resources found.
```

`get nodes` gives `No resources found` for any of the namespaces I have: `kube-system`, `kube-public`, or `default`.

```
$ kubectl get all --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/heapster-7ff8d6bf9f-qv56t               0/1       Pending   0          44m
pod/kube-dns-69ff9fcd66-ls9w7               0/3       Pending   0          11d
pod/kubernetes-dashboard-669f9bbd46-xthpq   0/1       Pending   0          45m
pod/monitoring-influxdb-cc95575b9-qjk4r     0/1       Pending   0          44m

NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
service/heapster               ClusterIP   <IP>             <none>        80/TCP          44m
service/kube-dns               ClusterIP   <IP>             <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   11d
service/kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   <IP>             <none>        443/TCP         45m
service/monitoring-influxdb    ClusterIP   <IP>             <none>        8086/TCP        44m

NAME                                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/aws-node                         0         0         0         0            0           <none>          11d
daemonset.apps/kube-proxy                       0         0         0         0            0           <none>          11d
daemonset.apps/nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset   0         0         0         0            0           <none>          34m

NAME                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/heapster               1         1         1            0           44m
deployment.apps/kube-dns               1         1         1            0           11d
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard   1         1         1            0           45m
deployment.apps/monitoring-influxdb    1         1         1            0           44m

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
replicaset.apps/heapster-7ff8d6bf9f               1         1         0         44m
replicaset.apps/kube-dns-69ff9fcd66               1         1         0         11d
replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-669f9bbd46   1         1         0         45m
replicaset.apps/monitoring-influxdb-cc95575b9     1         1         0         44m
```

UPDATE:

After I send a Kubernetes API call from my backend to launch some pods I get the following output (`kubectl get jobs` is similar) but still no actual instances spin up and the jobs never execute.

```
$ kubectl get svc
kubernetes                                      ClusterIP   <IP>     <none>        443/TCP                                                       14d
svc-3d1de3dc-7ca1-1f83-7a5e-548e5c5b4d12        NodePort    <IP>     <none>        8082:32433/TCP,8081:30374/TCP,8096:31178/TCP,8083:31067/TCP   1m
svc-3d1de3dc-7ca1-1f83-7a5e-548e5c5b4d12-sut0   ClusterIP   <IP>     <none>        50001/TCP                                                     1m
svc-7429ae6b-6f4b-012b-2d93-7c244109090b        NodePort    <IP>     <none>        8082:30736/TCP,8081:31272/TCP,8096:30857/TCP,8083:30949/TCP   1m
svc-7429ae6b-6f4b-012b-2d93-7c244109090b-sut0   ClusterIP   <IP>     <none>        50001/TCP                                                     1m
svc-89e81309-f6e4-21b1-ab8d-ecfb74d08010        NodePort    <IP>     <none>        8082:32072/TCP,8081:31236/TCP,8096:30000/TCP,8083:31257/TCP   1m
svc-89e81309-f6e4-21b1-ab8d-ecfb74d08010-sut0   ClusterIP   <IP>     <none>        50001/TCP                                                     1m
svc-c196e61f-098e-7b10-9d05-6d06ccbdbb9f        NodePort    <IP>     <none>        8082:32541/TCP,8081:30305/TCP,8096:31738/TCP,8083:31846/TCP   1m
svc-c196e61f-098e-7b10-9d05-6d06ccbdbb9f-sut0   ClusterIP   <IP>     <none>        50001/TCP                                                     1m
```

Comment: Has CloudFormation created the ECS instances for your nodes? If no, they are missing...If yes, connect to your instances and check the `kubelet` logs for errors, they maybe are in trouble to register to your control plane.

Comment: Do you mean has CloudFormation created the EC2 instances? I see the cluster in EKS dashboard but I don't see any EC2 instances associated with the cluster. I don't see any Events in CloudFormation > Stack > myStack > Events either. See the updated question for when I launch a cluster using the Kubernetes API from my backend. I imagine that the master should be visible always?

Comment: EKS [worker nodes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/worker.html) run in your AWS account as standard EC2 instances and connect to your cluster's control plane via the API server endpoint. The control plane (i.e., the master components) runs in an account managed by AWS, and it's always "hidden" from your point of view. See [Amazon EKS Clusters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/clusters.html).

Comment: If you are just getting started with EKS, [eksctl](https://eksctl.io/) is a great tool that creates all the AWS resources that you need when you create a cluster.

Comment: Hopefully you managed to fix this by now. The output shows that the CNI, aws-node, is not running. If that's not running, none of the other pods will start. Could be an authentication issue or a SG issue. As @Aposhian said, eksctl is a great way to get started.

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance you end up here as myself looking for an answer, you might also want to check [EKS Nodegroup scaling configuration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/catching-up-with-managed-node-groups-in-amazon-eks/), by going to EKS > Clusters > select your cluster > computing tab > select your node group and editing it.

In my case, an undocumented previous configuration left the cluster with zero nodes as maximum size, thus not allowing to create a node, hence the no nodes available message.